# Should you cache null checks?

Tags: java

I made a method which has multiple `@Nullable` parameters and contains multiply nested loops. Certain actions in the nested loops should only happen if the paramter is not `null`.

Should I save whether or not the paramters are available before I run the loops as a (`final`?) `boolean` or does it not make a real difference compared to null-checks inside the loop?

Comment: It likely doesn't make a difference. Focus on clarity and readability instead of micro-optimizations.

Comment: not needed for caching

Comment: A comparison with null is unlikely to take much more time than a boolean check. Best way to know: test and measure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the real question is which is more readable and that is really dependent on the code itself and who you ask :-) ... I would say that a null check has basically zero performance penalty so don't cache it thinking it is needed for some performance gain